# Clip data using GeoPandas or PostGIS

Tags: python, geopandas, pandas, geodataframe

I have two geodataframes - points. First gdf contains smaller number of points. I am trying to clip my second gdf (with higher number of points and therefore bigger area) to the extent of first gdf. What is the best/easiest/fastest way how to do it using Python or potentially PostGIS?

[image: example of my data]

Comment: One question per Question, please, as per the [Tour].

Comment: (It is considered multiple questions because you are asking both for a PostGIS and Geopandas solution)

Comment: No, OP is NOT asking for two solutions. OR means either approach is acceptable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [cx indexer](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/user_guide/indexing.html) method and total_bounds:

> coordinate based indexing with the cx indexer, which slices using a
> bounding box

```
import geopandas as gpd

fewpoints = gpd.read_file(r'C:/GIS/temp/randpoints100.shp')
manypoints = gpd.read_file(r'C:/GIS/bs_riks.shp')
#manypoints.shape
#Out[14]: (328851, 7)

xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax = fewpoints.total_bounds #Find the extent of the smaller layer
manypoints_filtered = manypoints.cx[xmin:xmax, ymin:ymax]
#manypoints_filtered.shape
#Out[15]: (23919, 7)

manypoints_filtered.to_file(r'C:/GIS/temp/bs_riks_filtered.shp')
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

In PostGIS you can extract the [extent](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Extent.html) of a layer, set its coordinate system (same as input) and at last select intersecting geometries from another layer:

```sql
with bbox as (
  select ST_SetSRID(st_extent(geom),4326) as geom 
  from point_layer1
  ) 
select * 
from point_layer2 pt 
 join bbox 
  on st_intersects(pt.geom2, bbox.geom);
```